# Shortcut key to auto-complete covering the next word in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

I am working on IntelliJ for MacOS. I am looking at options to auto-complete where the auto-complete also covers the next word. I know two shortcut keys to auto-complete right now. One is 'Tab' which replaces the next word and the other is 'Cmd + Shift + Enter' which covers the entire line. It is difficult to describe but here is my best effort:
1. I have a word like this public String getValue() and I want to covert it to public Optional getValue(). So I type public OptString getValue() and the Optional auto-complete pops up. What shortcut key can I hit such that that Optional covers the string in <> to change from OptString to Optional?
2. I have a statement like this return "h" + name. I want to change it to return Optional.of("h") + name but when I hit Cmd + Shift + Enter I get Optional.of("h" + name), i.e. it covers the entire line instead of just the next word. Any shortcut key for that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tab would replace `String` with `Optional`, Cmd+Shift+Enter replaces it with `Optional<String>`.
2. This replacement seems strange to me, as `Optional.of("h") + name` doesn't compile. There's no special shortcut for such surrounding right now. You can create a Surround live template yourself though (`java.util.Optional.of($SELECTION$)`).